# JPA Persistence Inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem which I am facing long time and I don't get the answer.

I would like to persist an Inheritance table with JPA and I got an error message. I use eclipselink for that.

My Unittest fails with that classes.

```
    -- Table: PERSON

CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    ID SERIAL  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    DEFAULT nextval ('Person_Sequence'),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    DTYPE VARCHAR
);

-- Table: BUYER

CREATE TABLE BUYER (
    ID INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I have a class and table person and a sub-class buyer from this class person

Person Class:

```
   import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public   class Person {

    @Id
    private int ID;
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    protected Person() {
    }

    public Person(int ID, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [getId()=" + getId() + ", getFirstName()=" + getFirstName() + ", getLastName()=" + getLastName()
                + "]";
    }

}
```

Buyer Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Buyer extends Person {

    protected Buyer() {
    };

    public Buyer(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

So far there is no error. But here you see my Unittest and the error message that I get:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BuyerTest {

    final private int id = 33;
    final private String firstName = "Bart";
    final private String lastName = "Simpson";

    static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    static EntityManager manager;
    static EntityTransaction transaction;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testEclipseLink");
        assertNotNull(factory);
        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        assertNotNull(manager);
        transaction = manager.getTransaction();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        if (manager == null)
            return;
        manager.close();
        factory.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void create() {
        transaction.begin();
        System.out.println("first " + firstName + "last " + lastName);
        Buyer buyer = new Buyer(id, firstName, lastName);
        assertNotNull(buyer);
        manager.persist(buyer);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Test
    public void modify() {
        Buyer buyer = manager.find(Buyer.class, id);
        assertNotNull(buyer);
        transaction.begin();
        buyer.setFirstName("Homer");
        transaction.commit();
        teardown();
        setup();
        buyer = manager.find(Buyer.class, id);
        assertEquals("Homer", buyer.getFirstName());
    }

    @Test
    public void remove() {
        Buyer buyer = manager.find(Buyer.class, id);
        assertNotNull(buyer);
        transaction.begin();
        manager.remove(buyer);
        transaction.commit();
        buyer = manager.find(Buyer.class, id);
        assertNull(buyer);
    }




}
```

So, if I run the test I got this error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-10-16 19:53:54.691--UnitOfWork(2036292945)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: NULL-Wert in Spalte »first_name« verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
  Detail: Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (33, null, null).
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO BUYER (ID) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

It tells me that I got a null constraint error on Firstname. But If I print the firstname on the console it is set.

I have tried and if I remove the inheritance and use juste my Buyer class it works fine! 
So I can not figure out where is my problem between the buyer and person class. 
Also if it is a Src- or Table definition problem

Comment: 3 things : 1. `BUYER.ID` column should be a FK which references `PERSON.ID`  2. In your `create` test, why are you setting the entity's id ? It should be set by your DB  3. Your tests will only succeed when they are run sequentially `create`-> `modify` -> `remove` which is neither guaranteed nor a good idea

Comment: The error shows that EclipseLink is issuing the expected "INSERT INTO BUYER (ID) VALUES (?)" statement - this will pass in only the ID.  It should have issued a separate statement into the PERSON table to insert the ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME fields.  Turn on SQL logging to see what is happening, but I suspect your database is NOT setup the way you mentioned.  Somehow your BUYER table is expecting FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME fields which don't exist in in the table model you've configured in JPA.  Maybe you meant to use InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS instead of JOINED?

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing that i can see it's that a buyer is a person so you need to reflect that in your schema adding a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE BUYER (
ID INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
personId bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
constraint fk_personId foreign key (personId) references PERSON (id)
```

);

Also in your child class you need the annotation.

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="personId")
```

A good idea is making all the IDs of the table auto incremental

Comment: `BUYER`'s PK should be a _shared_ key (ie. also a FK), there's no need for an additional FK. And there's no need for an annotation when it has the same name as `PERSON`'s